# Feasible to specify only year on Python's datetime module?

Tags: python, date, datetime

Is it feasible to only specify some data, such as `year`, on Python's `datetime` module?

So,

```
import datetime
date = datetime.date(2013, 7, 25)
```

In this example, is it feasible to get the following behaviour and if so, how can it be done?

```
date = datetime.date(2013, None, None) # this code issues an error, so I'd like to know any alternatives.
```

And if this cannot be done on Python, what's the best way to cope with `date` object on such cases?

Thanks.

Comment: Why not just store `year` in a variabe instead? A date is only valid if it is a valid date, e.g. has a year, month and day.

Comment: What are you trying to do, really?

Comment: Actually, 99% of my data are valid (i.e. have all of year, month, day). Only tiny amount of them are not, hence I consider how to cope with them...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`datetime.date` requires all three components: year, month and day. So you cannot skip any of them. If you need so special bahaviour define your own date class and use it appropriately.